# Excel: compare every other row with the one below and colorize cells if the value is greater

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

Consider the following data -

[image]

I want to compare every other row with the one below and colorize the cells if the value is greater as shown in the image.

If at all the data is sorted on some column, the colored cells should remain as they were initially. For example, the comparison should be between values `A` and `B` in `COL1` for the same value `ALPHA` in `COL2`.

Can this be achieved by writing a formula and how it would look like? Thanks SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional Formatting formula, applied to C2 (select C2 when creating the CF rule

```
=AND(MOD(ROW(), 2)=0, C2>OFFSET(C2,1,0))
```

Apply to your data block

[image]

Comment: Hi Chris - Thanks. I added an `)` at the end to complete the formula. Next, after navigating to `Format --> Conditional Formatting` I chose `Apply to range` as `C2:F7`, used the custom formula that you mentioned with red color under `Formatting styles`, but the sheet remained unchanged. Am i missing something?

Comment: Argh, I overlooked the manditory Column parameter.  Edited now, including an image to show it works

Comment: That worked! Thanks.